# Join mostrar somente datas posteriores

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela que registra etapas de uma movimentação.
Por exemplo:

> ```
>    Data    - Movimentacao - Produto
> 2018-01-10 - produzido    -   id1
> 2018-01-11 - embalado     -   id1
> 2018-01-12 - despachado   -   id1
> 2018-01-10 - produzido    -   id2
> 2018-01-10 - produzido    -   id3
> 2018-01-11 - embalado     -   id3
> 2018-01-10 - produzido    -   id4
> ```

Com a seguinte consulta consigo mostrar quais foram embalados e não despachados:

```
SELECT    l.id
FROM      (SELECT id FROM movimentacao WHERE movimento = 'embalado'  ) l
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM movimentacao WHERE movimento = 'despachado') r USING(id)
WHERE     r.id IS NULL
```

Porém se um produto for re-embalado é inserido outra linha com a movimentação "embalado".

> ```
>    Data    - Movimentacao - Produto
> 2018-01-10 - produzido    -   id1
> 2018-01-11 - embalado     -   id1
> 2018-01-12 - despachado   -   id1
> 2018-01-13 - embalado     -   id1
> ```

Então esse produto deveria entrar na consulta que mencionei acima, porém isso não acontece pois existe já uma movimentação de "despacho".
Gostaria de pegar aqueles registros que não existem "despacho" após "embalo", mesmo que já tenha existido anteriormente alguma movimentação de "despacho". Alguma sugestão de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que existem apenas os três status mostrados no exemplo (`produzido`, `embalado`, `despachado`), sugiro você pegar sempre a última ocorrência de cada `id`. Se for `despachado`, o item está finalizado; sendo `embalado`, retorna na sua consulta; e sendo `produzido`, está no início do processo:

```
-- precisa validar o nome dos campos e da tabela
SELECT * 
FROM tb_movimentacao m1
WHERE m1.data = (SELECT m2.data FROM tb_movimentacao m2 where m2.id = m1.id ORDER BY m2.data desc LIMIT 1)
  AND m1.movimento = 'embalado';
```

Se ajudar, tem um exemplo funcionando [**nesse fiddle**](https://rextester.com/KUCB40489).